# Performance Issue of SQLServer Columnstore Index: "Where OR" will influence predicate pushdown

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-optimization, columnstore

In SQL Server, I have a table using Columnstore Index, need to do some aggregate step, but if the where clause contains "or", the predicate pushdown will Gone, I don't know why, anyone have suggestion about this? For example,

In this query text:

```sql
select sum(num) from Fact where date = '2021-06-02' and NUMF = 23
```

Predicate pushdown will work perfect. But if I add a "OR" in the where clause, such as:

```
select sum(num) from Fact where date = '2021-06-02' or NUMF = 23
```

the predicate pushdown will not work, query plan will scan all columnstore index, which is very time consuming.

Is this a feature of SQLServer? Or a bug?

Comment: How is perf for this? `select sum(num) as num from ( select sum(num) as num from Fact where date = '2021-06-02' union all select sum(num) as num from Fact where NUMF = 23 and date <> '2021-06-02' ) t` (assumes `date` is not nullable)

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks for your reply, sure the perf of this query text is great, the predicate works, but sometimes the query text will be very complex and hard to modify it to use "UNION ALL", such as:

select sum(num) from Fact where date = '2021-06-02' or NUMF = 23 or column1 = 1 or column2 = 2 or column = 3 or column4 = 4.

So, I think it's a good idea to use "union all", but the scalability is not good enough.

Answer (score 0):

OR predicates on the same column are pushed down, [but when you use an OR predicate across different columns it can't be pushed down](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5939.workarounds-for-predicates-that-don-t-get-pushed-down-to-columnstore-scan-including-or.aspx). The `UNION ALL` workaround is highlighted in that post as well. If you think about how'd you implement it, it makes sense: columnstore is processing data a column at a time.

One reason why columnar processing is fast is because you operate on a single column at a time and you keep track of the rows in the column that qualify your predicate on that column. Once you're done with all the predicate evaluations you can go back to the rows from the aggregated column and compute the aggregate.

Thus it's easy to evaluate OR predicates on the same column and you can update your row list if you have AND predicates. In case a row doesn't qualify a later predicate you can always remove it from the list. However if you have OR predicates on multiple columns and a few AND predicates the order of evaluation really matters and you may need to revisit the same column multiple times so I think the implementation cost was too high for this to happen in the storage engine. I think an all OR predicate pushdown should be doable, though it probably adds additional complexity to segment elimination.